# Can't read csv file by csvparser

Tags: c, parsing, csv, clion

I use **CLion** code editor.
For parsing a csv file I use [C/C++ csvparser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvparser/).

This contend of data.csv:

```
Country,Continent,National Language
United States,North America,English
Canada,North America, French
Mexico,North America,Spainish
```

I created project named Tutorial. 
My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(Tutorial)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(Tutorial ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Tutorial csvparser)
```

The content of main.c. It is taken from its [official page](https://sourceforge.net/p/cccsvparser/wiki/Home/):

```
#include "csvparser.h"

int main() {
    int i =  0;
    //                                   file, delimiter, first_line_is_header?
    CsvParser *csvparser = CsvParser_new("data.csv", ",", 1);
    CsvRow *header;
    CsvRow *row;

    header = CsvParser_getHeader(csvparser);
    if (header == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", CsvParser_getErrorMessage(csvparser));
        return 1;
    }
    const char **headerFields = CsvParser_getFields(header);
    for (i = 0 ; i < CsvParser_getNumFields(header) ; i++) {
        printf("TITLE: %s\n", headerFields[i]);
    }
    // Do NOT destroy the headear manually if you plan to destroy the parser later.
    // If you destroy both header and parser, you will get double free runtime error
    // CsvParser_destroy_row(header);
    while ((row = CsvParser_getRow(csvparser)) ) {
        printf("==NEW LINE==\n");
        const char **rowFields = CsvParser_getFields(row);
        for (i = 0 ; i < CsvParser_getNumFields(row) ; i++) {
            printf("FIELD: %s\n", rowFields[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        CsvParser_destroy_row(row);
    }
    CsvParser_destroy(csvparser);

    return 0;
}
```

But it gives an error:

```
/home/ken/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Tutorial-9a39f70/9a39f70/Debug/Tutorial
Error opening CSV file for reading: data.csv : No such file or directory
```

Strange, but `data.csv' file actually exists in current folder.

I tried to have pass an absolute path, but it doesn't help. 
How can I avoid this problem?

**P.S** It it worth noting that when I compile this programm by `gcc main.c -I ../include ../src/csvparser.c -o main` all works fine.

Comment: why data.csv is in source files?

Comment: Have `main()` first report its current working directory.

Comment: Try creating a file `"dataxyz.csv"` from the program and find the folder where it was written.

Comment: Suspect code reports error when `header == NULL`.  Add check if `csvparser==NULL`.

Comment: @chux Yes, code reports when header == NULL

Comment: ... and was `csvparser==NULL` true?  Does `"data.csv"` have a header?

Comment: @chux it returns 1, but I actually have a header

Comment: Since `csvparser==NULL` is true, certainly the file is not where the code is looking for it.